# Change tooltip style template

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to be able to assign different tooltip styles to style of other controls

For example, I have style for my tooltip:

```
 <Style x:Key="BorderedInfoTooltip" TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
                    <Border Background="DarkSlateGray" BorderBrush="DarkGoldenrod" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Width="32" Height="32" Source="Resources/info.png" />
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

And style for my icon images:

```
    <Style x:Key="IconStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="20"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"></Setter>
    </Style>
```

How to make this buttons(with style == IconStyle) have my tooltip style?

Comment: I made small changes for which control it should be applied, assume we applied my tooltip to buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of have your tooltip outside the iconStyle, place it in the image style resources and skip the key like this:

```
<Style x:Key="IconStyle" TargetType="Image">
  <Style.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
            <Border Background="DarkSlateGray" BorderBrush="DarkGoldenrod" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="2">
              <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Width="32" Height="32" Source="Resources/info.png" />
                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
              </StackPanel>
            </Border>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </Style.Resources>
  <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
  <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"></Setter>
  <Setter Property="Width" Value="20"></Setter>
  <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"></Setter>
</Style>
```

**EDIT:**

Or you can leave it as a global or Windows Resources and reference it in the Iconstyle resources like this:

```
<Style x:Key="IconStyle" TargetType="Image">
  <Style.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ToolTip" BasedOn="{StaticResource BorderedInfoTooltip}" />
  </Style.Resources>
...
```

Comment: But i suppose other different controls will also probably have that tooltip style

Comment: @AndreyIschencko: see my addition.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you set your image style like this :

```
<Image Width="32" Height="32" Source="Resources/info.png" Style="{StaticResource IconStyle}"/>
```

Comment: Oh you dont get it. I have a lot  of images. I want to  have styled tooltip template, and this tooltip will include small info image `info.png`